# Is it time that [dhtml] dies?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is [dhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dhtml) still needed? This is such an archaic term. Wouldn't [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), etc. suffice?

Comment: Wait... are people not still writing DHTML in AJAX language? *throws manuscript in the trash*

Comment: @NathanOliver i wanted to gauge the community first before making the request.

Comment: Sorry, after reading the wiki I removed my comment.  I can't see why we even had it to begin with when a combination of tags using the actual technique should be preferred.  Just to make sure, DHTML is not an actual language but just an umbrella term, right?

Comment: @NathanOliver its an umbrella tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068253/edsac-17bit-and-35bit-integers

Comment: Still needed? Was it *ever* needed?

Comment: @animuson theoretically... when the term was in fashion

Comment: @HansPassant What is that link supposed to mean?

Comment: @Andrew That just because things are "obsolete" doesn't mean that there are no questions asked about them.